# date column in my sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I made a table in mysql, with for example `date_birth date` ;

and then tried to insert a date like this in it `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` but the inserted date is like this format `2012-08-02`, so do you know what's wrong? or maybe for long format of date is shouldn't use date in mysql ?

thanks!!

Comment: you have assigned datatype as date. if you also want to save time along with date then use "datetime" as your datatype. To alter table use - "ALTER TABLE `<db_name>`.`<table name>` CHANGE `date` `date` DATETIME NULL; "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter your mysql table with `date_birth DATETIME` instead of `date_birth DATE`

You can do this with below query:

`ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN date_birth DATETIME`

and then if you insert date like `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` it will take full date time not just date

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is correct:

> DATE(expr) Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression expr.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date